# How to get a list with all filenames with full path along with extension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have one folder say ABC in which i have so many files with extension say 001.py, 001.xls, 001.pdf and many more. I want to write one program in which we get list with this filename say

```
 ["C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\001.py", "C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\001.xls", "C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\001.pdf"]
```

MyCode:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path) #current path

cwd = os.getcwd()
list3 = []
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(cwd) if isfile(join(cwd, f))]
for i in onlyfiles:
    list3.append(dir_path+"\\"+i)
print(list3)
```

I am getting output as :

```
["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ABC\\001.py", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ABC\\001.xls", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ABC\\001.pdf"]
```

I am looking for output as :

```
["C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\001.py", "C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\001.xls", "C:\Users\Desktop\ABC\001.pdf"]
```

Comment: This is just how strings with backslashes are represented. Instead of `print(list3)`, try `for x in list3: print(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Python 3, [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) can help you assemble your paths in a clearer way! If you're forced to use Python 2, [you could bring in the library it's based off](https://pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/pep428/)!

The double-backslash occurs and needs to be dealt with because Windows bizarrely chose to use `\` instead of `/` as the path separator while it is ubiquitous as an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in many, especially C-derived languages. You can use `/` and it'll still work fine. You'll find need to escape spaces with `\` when not using `pathlib` too.

Comment: I got this. suppose i need to open some file with path like "C:\\User\\ABC\\abc.txt" will it open using Python script ??

Comment: @Anuj Practically, it's the difference between how strings are written, displayed, and stored. In order to represent some characters (such as the newline char `\n` or \\) when *building* a string, they are prefixed by \. They're stored as bytes with an associated encoding (such as `utf-8`). Then when printing, *some* representations will show the escape chars, and others will not, ideally depending on what's most practical, but not always (this is often much more obvious with newlines).

Comment: Apparently this also affects the SO comment system, so it's quite difficult to show single backslashes in a consistent way here.